# Как передать текст из Dialog, в котором EditText, в ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-edittext

Добрый день. Только учусь программировать и никак не могу найти рабочий способ передачи текста из `EditText` (который в диалоговом окне) в `ListView`:

```
public class CustomDialofFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @NonNull 
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()); 
        return builder.setTitle("имя") 
            .setView(R.layout.dialog) 
            .setPositiveButton("Далее", null) 
            .setNegativeButton("Отмена", null) 
            .create();
    }
}
```

Comment: если вам нужно передать значение с диалога, то создаете в диалоге метод, который будет передавать значение с EditText в ваше активити. Можно посмотретьна код диалога?

Comment: текст должен передаватся при нажатии на кнопку "Далее"?

Comment: Да, другого варианта из за отсутствия опыта я пока не вижу

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Примерно так все должно работать:

```
EditText editText;
View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.MY_ID);

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()); 
return builder 
    .setTitle("имя") 
    .setView(view) 
    .setPositiveButton("Далее", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            sendText(editText.getText().toString()))
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("Отмена", null) 
    .create();
```

Comment: Наверное реализацию метода `sendText()` тоже стоит добавить, в нм в общем то весь смысл взаимодействия.

Comment: Полностью согласен....